# VBA return an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which is meant to obtain the sheet names and put them into an array:

```
Function GetSheetNames(WBook) As String()
    Dim TempArray() As String        
    NoSheets = WBook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim TempArray(1 To NoSheets)
    For i = 1 To NoSheets
        TempArray(i) = WBook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i        
    GetSheetNames = TempArray
End Function
```

I tried to refactor the code to get rid of the `TempArray` variable:

```
Function GetSheetNames(WBook) As String()    
    NoSheets = WBook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim GetSheetNames(1 To NoSheets)
    For i = 1 To NoSheets
        GetSheetNames(i) = WBook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Function
```

However it returns an error. Is such thing even possible in VBA? Do I always need a temporary local variable inside a function which at the end gets assigned to the function name in order to return it?

Answer (score 2):

You need the temp array:

```
Function GetSheetNames(WBook As Workbook)
    NoSheets = WBook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim ary(1 To NoSheets)
    For i = 1 To NoSheets
        ary(i) = WBook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
    GetSheetNames = ary
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    Dim arry
    arry = GetSheetNames(ActiveWorkbook)
    For Each a In arry
        MsgBox a
    Next a
End Sub
```